# Need help with constructing a DFA

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

I am trying to construct the [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) that accepts the following language

$$ L_2 := \left\{ w \in \{a,b\}^* \mid \#a(w) \text{ is divisible by } 3 \text{ and } \texttt{babbab} \text{is a substring of } w \right\} $$

My solution is illustrated below. I feel like my current solution is incomplete/wrong.

[image]

Comment: $aaaababbab$ is in the language but not accepted by your DFA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea to construct such a DFA. Consider differently the two parts of the language: $L = L_1 \cap L_2$ where $L_1 = \{u\in\{a,b\}^*\mid |u|_a \equiv 0 \mod 3\}$ and $L_2 = \{ubabbabv\mid u,v\in \{a,b\}^*\}$.

Note that I reworded "being divisible by $3$" into "being equal to $0$ modulo $3$". This will help to contruct the automaton.

For such an automaton, you need to keep track of the value of $|u|_a \mod 3$. This can be done using only three states. An automaton recognizing $L_1$ could be the following one, where $q_i$ denotes the state where $|u|_a \equiv i \mod 3$:

[image: this one]

Now to build an automaton recognizing $L$, you can first build an automaton recognizing $L_2$, then triple each states and completing transitions according to the value of $|u|_a$.

Though, honestly, this is very tedious and annoying. The person giving this assignment could have chosen a short substring condition.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your help! I don't think I could've done it in such a simplistic, yet effective way.